Condition of differentiability of a two variable function
I recently came across this theorem that states:

If the partial derivatives of a function $f(x,y) : x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

$f$$_{x}$$(x,y)$ & $f$$_{y}$$(x,y)$ both exist and are continuous in a neighbourhood of some point (a,b)

Then the function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at the point (a,b)

My doubt is this:

Is the converse also true?

i.e. if a function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at the point (a,b) then is it necessary that $f$$_{x}$$(x,y)$ & $f$$_{y}$$(x,y)$ both exist and are continuous in a neighbourhood of the point (a,b)?

Edit:

This doubt arose due to the following problem:

$(x^{2}+y^{2})$ cos($\frac{1}{(x^{2}+{y}^2)^{1/2}}$)  for x,y $\ne$ 0,0

Assume 0 at 0,0

This function is differentiable at 0,0 but both the partial derivatives are not continuous. What is the reason that it fails to work here then?

@Medo differentiability at a point doesn’t imply partials exist and are continuous in a neighbourhood (the latter is equivalent to $Df$ existing and being continuous).

I have edited the question. I hope it is clearer now

The converse is not true as stated. What more is there to discuss?

I want to know the reason why it wont work conversely

see my first comment for the correct equivalence.
